# Select max value record from one-to-many join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to join two tables, but the second table contains multiple rows of parameters on which I wish to build by join.

**TABLE1**

```
+------------+-----------+
|   Ddate    |    ROOMNO |
+------------+-----------+
| 2018-22-11 |       101 |
| 2018-22-11 |       102 |
| 2018-22-11 |       103 |
| 2018-22-11 |       104 |
+------------+-----------+
```

**TABLE2** (Multiple rows per Room No)

```
+------------+-----------+------------------+
|   Ddate    |    ROOMNO |  MaxVoltage      |
+------------+-----------+------------------+
| 2018-22-11 |       101 |   230            |
| 2018-22-11 |       101 |   240            |
| 2018-22-11 |       101 |   250   -----MAX |
| 2018-22-11 |       102 |   230            |
| 2018-22-11 |       102 |   255   -----MAX |
+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

**DESIRED RESULT** (I want the Max Voltage for the Room on the Ddate)

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
|   Ddate    |    ROOMNO | MaxVoltage |
+------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-22-11 |       101 |        250 |
| 2018-22-11 |       102 |        255 |
| 2018-22-11 |       103 |        235 |
| 2018-22-11 |       104 |        238 |
| 2018-22-11 |       105 |        255 |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: How did you find 238 V for room 104?

Comment: In your example you have the same columns in Table2 as in Table1. Is that your real case?

Comment: This is not clear. In particular, "I want to join two tables" & "but the second table contains multiple rows of parameters on which I wish to build by join." Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear. But this is a(n obvious) duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t2.d, t2.roomno, max(t2.maxvolt)
FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.ddate = t2.ddate 
AND t1.roomno = t2.roomno
GROUP BY t2.d, t2.roomno;
```

Comment: Absent specific direction from OP, this could be further simplified to refer to table2 only - it has all the columns needed for this query.

Answer (score 0):

use subquery

```
    select t1.dDate,t1.roomno,mvoltage from table1 t1 join
    (select Ddate ,roomno,max(MaxVoltage ) as mvoltage from table2
    group by Ddate,roomno
    ) t2 on t1.Ddate=t2.Ddate
```

Comment: Thanks Zaynul.....But "MaxVoltage" column showing 'Null' values with above query..

Comment: Name that column in the sub-qeury.

Answer (score 0):

First you will join between two tables in a regular way, using the date and room no.
then use the aggregate function max for the voltage field with over clause , then  group by Room No and Date like following

```
select distinct t1.Ddate, t1.RoomNo, MAX(t2.MaxVoltage) over(partition by t1.RoomNo order by t1.Ddate) MaxVoltage
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t2.Ddate = t1.Ddate and t2.RoomNo = t1.RoomNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.maxvoltage
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.roomno = t1.roomno and t2.ddate = t1.ddate
      order by maxvoltage desc
     ) t2;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but with this query I am getting 'NULL' in MaxVoltage Column.

Comment: @KamodKartik . . . That would occur either when there is no match or when `maxvoltage` is `NULL` in `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.dDate,t1.roomno, mvoltage from table1 t1 join
    (select Ddate ,roomno,max(MaxVoltage ) as mvoltage from table2
    group by Ddate,roomno
    ) t2 on t1.Ddate=t2.Ddate and t1.Roomno = t2.RoomNo
```